# Is it possible to copy file from share point to amazon s3 or SAN storage?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, sharepoint, amazon-s3, copy

I have requirement to copy a file from share point to amazon s3 or SAN storage.
Is it possible to direct copy from share point to amazon s3? Or I have to first download a file from share point and than upload it to amazon s3 or SAN storage?

Comment: that depends on your sharepoint installation... there are several 3rd-party modules available for sharepoint... with plain sharepoint you will have to download and re-upload...

Comment: This is mistagged; it isn't about 'java' nor 'ruby-on-rails'

Answer (score 3):

There is no standard (SharePoint default adapters, connectors) for amazon s3 or SAN storage.

You can use third parties solutions that available on internet (easy goggling, don’t want to advert it :) )

If it is programmatic question then here is an amazing post:
http://dgoins.wordpress.com/2012/01/19/using-amazon-s3-as-a-media-hosting-option-for-sharepoint-2010/

take a look to implementation of **Storage Manager**

the official sources... 
below is the list of all SharePoint features: 
http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/product/Pages/Features.aspx 
We have official option to connect external sources by using the [Business Connectivity Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee518675).

But here no any official implementation of that for SAN or Amazon s3.

you can use [SAN to store the SharePoint Content Database](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/sharepoint/practices-implementing-sharepoint-san-141962), but this is not an option I guess, if we are talking about files.

Good luck! :-)